# What are the different hitpoints totals and/or armor values of each tank?

Tags: battlefield-1

Its kind of hard to compare the survivability of one tank against the others when taking hits.  The trucks seem to take the least amount of damage, followed by the one-man tank, and then the other multi-person tanks.  But its difficult to tell what the various hit point totals of each tank are, or how the different multi-person tanks compare to one another?

Is there any data on the hit points of each tank or how their armor compares against one another?

Is one tank more susceptible to rear attacks but others are not?